# Docker: during build phase, access a local file

Tags: docker

Is it possible to write a dockerfile such that I can access information from a local file during the build phase?  I am not trying to mount this file, I am trying to access its contents without specifying a variable argument.

For example, the following will not work for my situation:

```
// in the docker file
ARG my_variable
RUN echo "${my_variable}" > /tmp/whatever

// docker command
docker build --build-arg my_variable="$(cat /tmp/whatever)" ...
```

Why? Suppose I have an arbitrary number of files, with an arbitrary number of argument variables that I need to define, all of which must be hard coded: thus, there is a problem.

---

Instead, it would be useful to be able to do the following:

```
// in the dockerfile, in psuedo code, where I am symbolizing 
// access of the host os shell with double backticks 

VAR my_variable=``$(cat some_file)``

// then, perhaps later
VAR my_variable=``$(cat some_other_file)``
```

Is there a way to do this in docker?

Comment: `ADD/COPY` is not you want?

Comment: @atline so I am trying to store ssh keys in an intermediate build phase, where I might have one ssh key for x, another for y, etc... I figured if it was secure to simply add the file in to the intermediate build, there wouldn’t be such a large number of answers recommending storing the keys as an argument variable

Answer (score 1):

> so I am trying to store ssh keys in an intermediate build phase, where I might have one ssh key for x, another for y, etc... I figured if it was secure to simply add the file in to the intermediate build, there wouldn’t be such a large number of answers recommending storing the keys as an argument variable

If your aim is just want to add some secret things when do `docker build` & additional `not want to keep them in built out docker image`, then I think these answers which recommend to use args is out of date now.

You could use [Docker Build secret information](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/#new-docker-build-secret-information), also see [this](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/blob/master/frontend/dockerfile/docs/experimental.md#run---mounttypesecret):

> **RUN --mount=type=secret**
>   This mount type allows the build container to access secure files such as private keys without baking them into the image.

***A minimal example as next:***

**Dockerfile:**

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:experimental
FROM alpine
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=mysecret,dst=/foobar cat /foobar
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=mysecret2,dst=/foobar2 cat /foobar2
```

**mysecret.txt:**

```
HEREHEREHEREHERE111111111111111111111111111111111111
```

**mysecret2.txt:**

```
THERETHERETHERE2222222222222222222222222222222222222
```

**Build command:**

```
$ DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build --no-cache --progress=plain --secret id=mysecret,src=mysecret.txt --secret id=mysecret2,src=mysecret2.txt -t abc:1 .
```

**The build log:**

```
#1 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
......
#9 [2/3] RUN --mount=type=secret,id=mysecret,dst=/foobar cat /foobar
#9       digest: sha256:f9c85b682995c7282a89e769894571de46aa2fd3b433168e36f1f2a7f90322fe
#9         name: "[2/3] RUN --mount=type=secret,id=mysecret,dst=/foobar cat /foobar"
#9      started: 2019-08-02 03:22:43.288232033 +0000 UTC
#9 0.919 HEREHEREHEREHERE111111111111111111111111111111111111
#9    completed: 2019-08-02 03:22:45.467111192 +0000 UTC
#9     duration: 2.178879159s


#10 [3/3] RUN --mount=type=secret,id=mysecret2,dst=/foobar2 cat /foobar2
#10       digest: sha256:76e3ae52c6222cd45683599f634c126345e90eb0161dd87b7e74bd09e9bf2361
#10         name: "[3/3] RUN --mount=type=secret,id=mysecret2,dst=/foobar2 cat /foobar2"
#10      started: 2019-08-02 03:22:45.551609323 +0000 UTC
#10 1.313 THERETHERETHERE2222222222222222222222222222222222222
#10    completed: 2019-08-02 03:22:47.859417448 +0000 UTC
#10     duration: 2.307808125s
```

You can see 2 secrets already been used in `Dockerfile`. And also confirm after build, you could not get any secret from image:

```
$ docker run --rm abc:1 cat /foobar
$ docker run --rm abc:1 cat /foobar2
$
```